# Ansible 2.5 import_tasks, always and skip-tags

Tags: ansible

I have the following (stripped down) Ansible

```
- import_tasks: clever_stuff.yml
  tags: do-stuff
```

Inside clever_stuff.yml I have

```
- Name: Task1
  ... stuff ...

- Name: Task2
  ... stuff ...

- Name: Task3
  set_fact:
    my_var:     "{{ result.of.above.stuff }}"
  
- Name: Default case
  ... stuff ...
  when:
    - my_var is not defined
  tags: always
```

I then invoke this as part of a playbook from the command line

```
# ansible-playbook clever.yml --skip-tags do-stuff
```

and nothing from that imported task gets run.

My reading of the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html) is that all tasks in the imported file have the tags applied, so my "Default case" is actually tagged with "always, do-stuff", and I have said skip do-stuff. However the docs also say "There is a special always tag that will always run a task, unless specifically skipped (--skip-tags always)", so my expectation is that task should be getting executed because I haven't explicitly stated --skip-tags always.

**Why is it ignoring the always?**

My current work around is to wrap Tasks 1,2 & 3 in a block and tag that with do-stuff instead of the tags on the import_tasks, but it is not optimal for my actual use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with tasks being imported or not.

The reason is because `always` was implemented as a special tag to execute a task even if Ansible was called with `--tags` option and some tag, and **not** for overriding `--skip-tags`.

Consider this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: first task
      debug:
      tags:
        - do-stuff

    - name: second task
      debug:
      tags:
        - always

    - name: third task
      debug:
      tags:
        - always
        - do-stuff
```

The third task is effectively what your imported tasks look like.

If you run this playbook with `--skip-tags do-stuff` any task which has `do-stuff` specified will not be run (i.e., first and third).

If you run this playbook with `--tags other-tag` then the second and third task will be run (that's what `always` is used for).

Comment: I don't understand how this is not about not importing tasks. If you're saying that `--skip-tags do-stuff` will not execute any task with that tag, then the `import_tasks` module is (supposedly) not going to be executed. To prove my point, he says that `'nothing from that imported task gets run'`. Please explain it to me how this is not about `'tasks being imported or not'`.

Comment: Because that's how `import_tasks` works. It applies the specified tag to each task being imported. As there is `tag: do-stuff` declaration, it gets applied to each task and nothing runs, because of what I explained above (coincidentally it has the same effect as you describe "*to prove your point*"). If you wanted to disprove your point, however, test with `--tags` instead of `--skip-tags` and check if it has any effect on the inclusion itself; also play with `import_tasks` and `include_tasks` to learn the difference.

Comment: So it seems that --skip-tags comes before --tags, and always is just a special tag that is automatically added to --tags (but not as special as I was trying to make it). So if I had a task with "tags: A, B" and then ran with "--tags A --skip-tags B", I should expect the task to be skipped?

Answer (score -1):

By executing the command:

> ```
> ansible-playbook clever.yml --skip-tags "do-stuff"
> ```

you are basically saying to not execute the tasks with that tag. What you want to do does not work because you are skipping the `import_tasks` module, thereby not importing the tasks from `clever-stuff.yml`.

If you need me to explain anything, just comment.

Comment: So it seems that --skip-tags comes before --tags, including always. If I had a task with tags A, B and then ran with "--tags A --skip-tags B" I should expect the task to be skipped

Comment: @Martin, the problem is that the `create.yml` playbook does not import any task with the tag `always`. So, basically, there is no tag `always`.

Comment: "*thereby not importing the tasks from `clever-stuff.yml`*" ー this statement is false. It would be true for `include_tasks`, but OP asked about `import_tasks`. To check if the file is really imported or not, simply introduce a syntax error to the tasks-file (`clever_stuff.yml`). With `import_tasks` you'll get an error.